# SqlException: Coluna 'Id' especificada várias vezes para 'a'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, framework

Estou com um erro ao tentar fazer multiplos joins em C# utilizando FromSqlInterpolated, estoura um erro: SqlException: Coluna 'Id' especificada várias vezes para 'a'.
O que pode estar errado?

```
 public DocumentationAvaliationViewModel GetInstitution(int IdInst)
    {

        List<AvaliationModel> listAvaliation = new List<AvaliationModel>();
        var result = _context.Documentations.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTATIONS AS D LEFT JOIN [USER] AS U ON D.UserId = U.Id RIGHT JOIN AVALIATIONS AS A ON A.UserId = U.ID RIGHT JOIN [Institution] I ON D.InstitutionId = I.Id LEFT JOIN AVERAGE AS J ON I.Id = J.InstitutionId WHERE I.ID = {IdInst} ").FirstOrDefault() ;

        var avaliations = (from u in _context.User
                           join t in _context.Avaliations
                           on u.Id equals t.UserId
                           where t.InstitutionId == IdInst
                           select new {  u.Name, u.photo_uri, t.Note, t.Comment }
                           );
        foreach (var i in avaliations)
        {
            listAvaliation.Add(new AvaliationModel
            {
                Comment = i.Comment,
                User = new UserModel
                {
                    Name = i.Name,
                    photo_uri = i.photo_uri,
                },
                Note = i.Note
            });
        }

        DocumentationAvaliationViewModel documentations = new DocumentationAvaliationViewModel()
        {
            Avaliations = listAvaliation,
            Institution = new InstitutionModel
            {
                Id = result.Institution.Id,
                InstitutionName = result.Institution.InstitutionName,
                Cep = result.Institution.Cep,
                Description = result.Institution.Description,
                District = result.Institution.District,
                Number = result.Institution.Number,
                Cnpj = result.Institution.Cnpj,
                Email = result.Institution.Email,
                OwnerName = result.Institution.OwnerName,
                Address = result.Institution.Address,
               
            },
        };

        return documentations;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, ao analisar seu código percebi que você está selecionando todas as colunas (*) de várias tabelas, incluindo a tabela 'DOCUMENTATIONS' (D), 'USER' (U), 'AVALIATIONS' (A), 'INSTITUTION' (I) e 'AVERAGE' (J). O erro pode estar ocorrendo porque essas tabelas têm colunas com o mesmo nome, como 'Id'. Tenta especificar as colunas que deseja selecionar, você tirando o asterisco pode resolver seu problema com o erro que relatou. Nessa função **"FromSqlInterpolated"**, é importante que você nomeie as colunas na seleção para evitar problemas. Espero que ajude. ATT.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).